# Django how to add double filter in admin page add model(foreign field items)

Tags: django, django-admin

```
class BodyPart(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class Exercise(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    body_part_primary = models.ForeignKey(BodyPart, on_delete=models.CASCADE)



class ExerciseTracker(models.Model):
    time = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    exercise = models.ForeignKey(Exercise, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

In the above code, the Excercise model includes the BodyPart model as a foreign key.
While adding a new ExerciseTracker entry on the admin page it shows a drop-down of the foreign key.
But How to add a filter for exercise based on BodyPart in ExerciseTracker? So that the field is a double dropdown

Answer (score 0):

You can add these to the search field by using a double underscore (`__`) to look "through" relations:

```
from django.contrib import admin

class ExerciseTrackerModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ['exercise__body_part_primary__name']
```

Comment: Thanks for going through it. The above solution is to check for existing records. I would like to have the option while adding a new entry

Comment: Ideally a two-stage drop down.